# Playwright: .count() returns always 0 but .nth()/first()/last() returns element

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I have spent for two days to figure out what the issue is.

I have a selector `this.table` which is working. I verified the locator by using `npx playwright open --> Pick locator`. The table has 50 rows but 27 are filled. The 27 rows are <tr id=xx ...> ...</tr> and the rest are <tr empty>...</tr>.
So IMO I get only the rows which have attribute `id`.

```
constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page
        this.dialog = page.getByRole("dialog").locator("div")
        this.table = this.page.locator(".table-body").locator("tbody").locator("tr[id]")
    }
```

I am using `@playwright/test: ^1.36.1`

When I execute my test and invoke `.count()` to know how many elements I have (expect 27) then I always get 0.

```
test("update entity", async ({page}) => {
        const payload = my_object.table
        console.log(await payload.count())
    })
```

When I use `.all()` I get `[]` as a result

```
test("update entity", async ({page}) => {
        const payload = my_object.table
        console.log(await payload.all())
    })
```

However, if I use `.nth(0)`, `first()` or `.last()` I receive concrete data

```
test("update entity", async ({page}) => {
        const payload = my_object.table
        console.log(await payload.first().innerText())
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Please share the relevant html snippet as well containing parent of the table , table and rows in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because .all() (nor .count()) don’t necessarily wait for the locator to be visible (ref. [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-all)), unlike .first(), .last() and .nth(0). Try asserting the locator to be visible, and the do an .all():

```js
test("update entity", async ({ page }) => {
    const payload = my_object.table
    await expect(payload.first()).toBeVisible() // or another appropriate assertion to assert that page is loaded
    console.log(await payload.all())
})
```

Comment: Thx @candre. Your solution helps. I always skip the note `all()` and `count()` don´t do an await . Thy very much.

Comment: This is incorrect to say that all() "don't do an await" . There is an subtle difference.Await is for waiting for an promise to be resolved before proceeding. In this scenario , as its not an web assertion , it won't wait till a certain state and will bring back the results immediately, whatever is available at that time however it *will* AWAIT for the promise to be resolved.

Comment: You are correct, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

`locator.count()` is not supposed to wait, it returns the number of elements which are found at the time you issue the command.

To wait for elements, you should use the [web-first assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions):

```
await expect(page.locator('.someLocator').toHaveCount(5)
```

which waits automatically until the condition is met ot it times out.